# Eclipse Milo: Does method support argument array?

Tags: java, methods, opc-ua, milo

OPCUA server have a method with one input argument
e.g.

```
protected Variant[] invoke(InvocationContext invocationContext, Variant[] inputValues) {
        logger.debug("Invoking sqrt() method of objectId={}", invocationContext.getObjectId());

        double x = (double) inputValues[0].getValue();
        double xSqrt = Math.sqrt(x);

        return new Variant[]{new Variant(xSqrt)};
}
```

At the OPCUA client, can I call this method with array int? e.g.[1,4,9,16,25]

```
CallMethodRequest request = new CallMethodRequest(
            objectId,
            methodId,
            new Variant[]{new Variant(input)}
);
```

At here, the inputArguments is Variant array, can I set with [1,4,9,16,25] and get [1,2,3,4,5]?

Comment: Not change the OPCUA server, at the OPCUA client, can it work like a stream? If it support, how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way.

You can send 5 `CallMethodRequest`s inside one `CallRequest`, though.

Comment: By the way, (at client) how to get input argument is ARRAY or not? and the ARRAY.length. If I change the OPCUA server use the input argument as array. e.g. "Object oInput = inputValues[0].getValue(); double x = (double) Array.get(oInput, i);" At the OPCUA client browse, how to found the input argument must ARRAY, and the ARRAY size? valuerank?

Comment: It's always an array. Sometimes it has 0 or 1 elements, sometimes more. ValueRank attribute will tell you how many dimensions a datatype has. ArrayDimensions attribute will tell you the size of each dimension. Clients will usually read a method node's InputArguments and OutputArguments properties to find out what inputs/outputs are expected.

Comment: And if you're asking about how to figure out if the any given argument is supposed to be an array or not, that information would be found in the `Argument` structure you got from reading the `InputArguments` and `OutputArguments` properties.

Comment: e.g. At server have a method with an InputArguments.DataType=Identifiers.Int32 and ValueRank=2 and ArrayDimensions=[3,4]. At the client, Can I call the method with input like [5,6]? or [[5,6]]? or [[5,6],[],[]]?

Comment: I think in this case the server is expecting a 2d array, up to something like `[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]` in size.

Comment: I means how about Java Irregular array? [5,6] missing a dimension; [[5,6]] have two dimension,but is Irregular; [[5,6],[],[]] some dimension without element.

Comment: I think that would be at the server's discretion.